# Intel 8086 TASM - illegal number

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

I've been doing a program, where I need to compare the values of a register to a certain number. While emulating on emu8086 I had no troble, however TASM compiler gave me error on all lines as such:

```
cmp bx, 0xF7F0h
```

The error looks like this:

```
***Error*** div.ASM(163) Illegal number
```

Any ideas how to solve this? 
 Of course I could put the `F7F0h` value into another register, or a variable, but I'd prefer keeping it a constant value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TASM doesn't understand the `0x...` notation. If it complains about `F7F0h` (because it thinks that this is a label), you have to add a leading zero: `0F7F0h`.

Answer (score 1):

```
cmp bx, 0xF7F0h
```

You used 2 methods for specifying hexadecimal at the same time!
You wrote the prefix **0x** as well as the suffix **h**.

Either use the prefixed form `cmp bx, 0xF7F0` or the suffixed form `cmp bx, 0F7F0h`. The latter has a prepended zero to avoid any conflict with the name of a label.